# C# Devexpress How to code the CheckBox column header to select or deselect all

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

How to use C# code to program Devexpress gridView checkbox column header to show as check box, once it check or uncheck, it will select or deselect all the check box of the data row.

I already know how to program the check box below, i just could not find any clue to do the above. Need advise from all the master as i could.

Thank you, 
Brian

```
RepositoryItemCheckEdit repositoryCheckEdit1 = gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;
repositoryCheckEdit1.ValueChecked = "True";
repositoryCheckEdit1.ValueUnchecked = "False";
gridView1.Columns["Item"].ColumnEdit = repositoryCheckEdit1;
```

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q107208

Comment: The GridControl already has a built-in checkbox selection system. See: [Multiple Row Selection via Built-In Check Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439)

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = True;
```

`GridView1.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect;` `GridView1.OptionsSelection.ShowCheckBoxSelectorInColumnHeader =    DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;`

Comment: Can you try to explain a little better what the code is doing?

Comment: First you activate the multi-select mode in the gridView, later you say that you will use a checkbox to select the rows in the grid.
In the end you also put a checkBox if you are going to use a filter line